# Grabbing a list from a multi-dimensional hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, multidimensional-array

In Programming Perl (the book) I read that I can create a dictionary where the entries hold an array as follows:

```
$wife{"Jacob"} = ["Leah", "Rachel", "Bilhah", "Zilpah"];
```

Say that I want to grab the contents of `$wife{"Jacob"}` in a list. How can I do that?

If I try:

```
$key = "Jacob";
say $wife{$key};
```

I get:

```
ARRAY (0x56d5df8)
```

which makes me believe that I am getting a reference, and not the actual list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See

- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html),
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

for information on using complex data structures and references.

Essentially, a hash can only have *scalars* as values, but references are scalars, Therefore, you are saving an arrayref inside the hash, and have to *dereference* it to an array.

To dereference a reference, use the `@{...}` syntax.

```
say @{$wife{Jacob}};
```

or

```
say "@{$wife{Jacob}}"; # print elements with spaces in between
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess by this time you must be knowing that 
`$` refers to a scalar 
and `@` refers to an array.

since you yourself said that the value for that key is an array,then you should

```
say @wife{$key};
```

instead of

```
say $wife{$key};
```